# C# Simple Web Server Image Read-In

Tags: c#, webserver, jpeg, httplistener, httplistenerrequest

So I'm back with another question about my web server. I've added several new features to it since my last question, but now I've ran into another problem.

I'm trying to allow the server to serve out an image that is called through HTML. However, the image isn't displaying on the webpage for some reason. I've stepped through the code and it does seem to be sending through the file, but it's just not displaying on the other end. Here is my code:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace miniWebServer_csc360
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static int requestCount = 0;
        public static Boolean singleUse = true;

        public static HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();

        //public static HttpListenerContext context;
        //public static HttpListenerResponse response;

        static Form1 thisform;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            thisform = this;
        }

        private void start_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(serverThread);
            t.Start();
        }

        public static void serverThread()
        {
            if (singleUse)
            {
                listener.Prefixes.Add("http://10.211.55.4:69/");
                listener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:69/");

                singleUse = false;
            }

            if (listener.IsListening)
                listener.Stop();

            else
                listener.Start();

            if (listener.IsListening)
            {
                thisform.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { thisform.status_label.Text 
                   = "Listening..."; });
                thisform.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { thisform.start_button.Text 
                   = "Stop Server"; });
            }

            else
            {
                thisform.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { thisform.status_label.Text 
                   = "Not listening..."; });
                thisform.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { thisform.start_button.Text 
                   = "Start Server"; });
            }

            while (listener.IsListening)
            {
                try
                {
                    HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();
                    HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;

                    requestCount++;

                    thisform.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { thisform.counter.Text 
                       = requestCount.ToString(); });

                    string page = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() 
                        + context.Request.Url.LocalPath;

                    if (context.Request.Url.LocalPath != "/HEAD.html" 
                         && context.Request.Url.LocalPath != "/favicon.ico")
                    {
                        if (context.Request.Url.LocalPath == "/")
                        {
                            string path = context.Request.Url.LocalPath + "index.html";
                                 thisform.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                            {
                                thisform.request_Box.AppendText(path + "\r\n");
                            });
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            thisform.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                            {
                                thisform.request_Box.AppendText
                                  (context.Request.Url.LocalPath + "\r\n");
                            });
                        }
                    }

                    if (context.Request.Url.LocalPath == "/")
                        page += "index.html";

                    TextReader tr = new StreamReader(page);
                    string msg = tr.ReadToEnd();

                    byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg);

                    if (context.Request.Url.LocalPath == "/header.html")
                    {
                        File.WriteAllText(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/HEAD.html",
                            context.Request.HttpMethod + " " +
                            context.Request.RawUrl + " HTTP/" 
                            + context.Request.ProtocolVersion + "\n"
                            + context.Request.Headers.ToString());
                    }

                    response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
                    Stream st = response.OutputStream;
                    st.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                    context.Response.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception error)
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you narrow down the issue a bit?  What is the actual response from this server?  What are its headers and content when it's serving the image?  Is there perhaps an error being caught and entirely ignored in that `catch` block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set HttpListenerResponse.ContentType to the appropriate MIME type for the image, such as "image/gif".

In addition, the example code is reading the image through a TextReader and converting it to a UTF8 byte array.  That's not going to work for binary files; it'll mangle the bytes.  You need to read those files with a FileStream or any other approach that will return the binary file contents unmodified.

Comment: How exactly do I get the content type?

Comment: The content type depends on the file format.  You can usually infer it from the file extension.  Just try handling the one case you have now, look at the extension and when you see that extension, return the appropriate ContentType for that one extension (hard-coded).  Once that works, your question then becomes how to get a good list of extensions to mime types, which there are other good answers for already.

Comment: I tried doing this, but it still isn't showing on the other side.

Comment: Hi Chris - I just noticed that you're reading all files with a TextReader.  That won't work with an image as it will modify the bytes in the and result in an invalid image.  You need to read binary files with something that won't modify the bytes, such as a FileStream.  If you aren't going to transcode text files from UTF-8 to other encodings then you can read text files with a binary file reader too; just make sure that the text files are saved as UTF-8 first (we do this in our server).

Comment: That makes sense, I'm looking at the documentation for FileStream, but I can't seem to figure out how to implement it into my code. Could you point me in the right direction?